# Fix comma separated values in a database

Tags: mysql

I have made a mistake of storing priorities as comma separated list in a column, further more its not even proper set
e.g. I have the following data

```
programs
HID
HID,IWREM
IWREM,ENVENG
ENVENG,HID
HID,ENVENG,IWREM
IWREM
```

Now what I need is to make it a proper comma separated list, by proper I mean there should be two commas in all values (since there are three programs) e.g. the first value HID should really by HID,, and the second should be HID,IWREM,

This is required because I want to run a query like this:

```
/* 2nd Priority Stats */
select 
sum(case when program like '%,HID%' then 1 else 0 end) as `IWRM`,
sum(case when program like '%,IWRM%' then 1 else 0 end) as `IWRM`,
sum(case when program like '%,ENVENG%' then 1 else 0 end) as `ENVENG`
from table where degree = 'me';
```

Similarly I want stats for all the three priorities.

I have 3 programs in total that students can enroll into namely HID, IWREN, ENVENG. They are abbr e.g. hid is hydraulics, irrigation & drainage etc

Schema is pretty simple student table with id, name, fathers name, programs, degree and other fields.
Student can select  one program, two or all three. In case of more than one is selected he must specify priorities. Current php code only inserts the programs as comma separated list however if student selects only one program there's no comma separated list and for two programs there are only two cols instead of all three.

Comment: Store the values in three columns (or in a junction table with three rows).  Don't use weird string operations in SQL, when a proper data structure allows you to use proper SQL statements.

Comment: i would spend no time at all on this approach. clean the data

Comment: is this a new system, or one that has so much data and inertia that a change would make it highly unlikely ?

Comment: @DrewPierce Problem is the data is already in that form on production server. Alternatively I can write a php script that will fix the issue but I dont think thats right approach, instead write a stored procedure perhaps and run it one time and make sure to fix the php code to make it three cols that is inserting the records.

Comment: but can you stage the change on a dev server, beat on it, beat on the migration script, and get it into production once and for all. those codes can really mess up CRUD if not in junction tables. those junction tables can have those **priorities** you were mentioning to @GordonLinoff

Comment: There are scripts you can run that will auto populate junction tables for you. btw, and I am reading tea-leaves here, when you say " make it three cols that" ... I think, well that is better than what you have, but short of nirvana ... you need a junction table.

Comment: @drew pierce can you show me how should the junction table look like? I think i will also need a look up table listing all the programs?

Comment: i would be glad to MC. Can you supply a `schema` as I or others can give you an example. Just the relevant tables of course, say 3 or 4 as an example

Comment: Dont know how to provide a schema its just one table namely student. Program names are at the moment hard coded in php.

Comment: @DrewPierce Alright I got it now. Actually I wasnt aware of Junction table, I call them simply join or Cross ref table.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Your data structure is all messed up.  It should be either three columns, or a junction table with three rows per entity.  That said, I have no idea why you need to change anything.  Why not just use the proper built-in functions?

```
select sum(find_in_set('HID', program) > 0) as `HID`,
       sum(find_in_set('IWRM', program) > 0) as `IWRM`,
       sum(find_in_set('ENVENG', program) > 0) as `ENVENG`
from table
where degree = 'me';
```

In MySQL, you don't need `case` to count the number of matches to a boolean expression.

Comment: I cant use that, because the commas represent priorities. I want to know how many students have selected HID as their 1st, 2nd & 3rd Priorities. In other words what are popular programs

Comment: You can use `find_in_set()` to determine the position.  However, I really think you should fix the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed a quick solution without changing too much php code for data insertion and reading, I made the fix by properly adding 2 commas.
Now the data looks like this:

```
id  program
1   "ENVENG,IWRM,HID"
3   "ENVENG,,"
9   "IWRM,,"
13  "HID,IWRM,"
18  "ENVENG,,"
21  "IWRM,HID,"
23  "HID,,"
27  "ENVENG,,"
```

I can now use select query with like for summing up data to be used for morris charts:

```
select 
sum(case when program like '%,HID,%' then 1 else 0 end) as `IWRM`,
sum(case when program like '%,IWRM,%' then 1 else 0 end) as `IWRM`,
sum(case when program like '%,ENVENG,%' then 1 else 0 end) as `ENVENG`
from table where degree = 'me';
```

However, this doesnt work if I had 4 or more programs and besides this technique just sucks. So as @gordon Linoff & @Drew Pierce suggests, it should be with junction table

Did you mean like this:

```
Student table (junction, lookup or i dont know)
Id    PID
1     3
1     2
1     1
3     3
9     2
13    1
13    2
....

Program Table
PID  Program
1    HID
2    IWREM
3    ENVENG
```

OR

```
Student Table
Id  program (pri-keys from program table)
1   3,2,1
3   3
9   2
13  1,2
18  3
21  2,1
......
```